# how to install PostgreSQL functions in python?

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I want to modify a PostgreSQL database through Python. Like Putting info in Python. It will process and classify the data in PSQL Database automatically. How to?

Simple Question :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. If you want to know which package to install to interface python with postgresql it is  psycopg2.

Comment: There is no way to do what you write "automatically"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[psycopg2](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2) is a solid wrapper for PostgreSQL. From the docs:

```
DSN = 'dbname=test'

## don't modify anything below this line (except for experimenting)

class SimpleQuoter(object):
    def sqlquote(x=None):
        return "'bar'"

import sys
import psycopg2

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    DSN = sys.argv[1]

print("Opening connection using dsn:", DSN)
conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
print("Encoding for this connection is", conn.encoding)

curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("SELECT 1 AS foo")
print(curs.fetchone())
curs.execute("SELECT 1 AS foo")
print(curs.fetchmany())
curs.execute("SELECT 1 AS foo")
print(curs.fetchall())

conn.rollback()

sys.exit(0)

curs.execute("SELECT 1 AS foo", async=1)

curs.execute("SELECT %(foo)s AS foo", {'foo':'bar'})
curs.execute("SELECT %(foo)s AS foo", {'foo':None})
curs.execute("SELECT %(foo)f AS foo", {'foo':42})
curs.execute("SELECT %(foo)s AS foo", {'foo':SimpleQuoter()})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. sorry if it's a bit confusing. but my concept got cleared :)